# Some operations on pandas DataFrames take hundreds of times longer on slightly larger data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, bioinformatics

I have DataFrames that have species indicators as columns, in these examples 30, and a variable amount of rows, the examples here are 450_631 (*low*) and 948_084 (*high*). In reality I have tens of thousands of these DataFrames, which is why performance is important to me.

The DataFrames contain zeros and ones.

[low DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkYK3.png)

|  | homo_sapiens.13 | pan_paniscus.13 | ... | capra_hircus.12 | equus_caballus.17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 450629 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 | 1 |
| 450630 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 | 0 |

[high DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSNaH.png)

|  | homo_sapiens.20 | gorilla_gorilla.20 | ... | macaca_fascicularis.10 | panthera_pardus.KV860304.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 948082 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 |
| 948083 | 0 | 1 | ... | 1 | 1 |

What I want to do now for example is to calculate the cumulative sum using the pandas function cumsum.

What I have observed is that for "small" DataFrames, like the example *low*, it takes a fraction of a second. However, some of the larger DataFrames, like the example *high*, take up to a few minutes, even though it's only roughly double the data.

[low cumsum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCumR.png), calculation takes ~ 0.2 s

|  | homo_sapiens.13 | pan_paniscus.13 | ... | capra_hircus.12 | equus_caballus.17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 450629 | 0 | 2606 | ... | 73099 | 72252 |
| 450630 | 0 | 2606 | ... | 73099 | 72252 |

[high cumsum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsM40.png), calculation takes ~
150 s

|  | homo_sapiens.20 | gorilla_gorilla.20 | ... | macaca_fascicularis.10 | panthera_pardus.KV860304.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | ... | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 948082 | 0 | 8463 | ... | 39761 | 239050 |
| 948083 | 0 | 8464 | ... | 39762 | 239051 |

I have observed similar patterns when copying (DataFrame.copy()) or indexing (DataFrame[list_of_indices]).
I don't understand why some operations on these larger DataFrames take an unreasonably longer amount of time compared to the smaller ones.

**EDIT:**

Ran the same process on my local, much much weaker laptop and **high.cumsum()** finishes in ~ 1.6 s, which seems very reasonable. This indicates the problem should be with the CPU or how the server works, which is way over my head.

**EIDT2:**

It seems like the problem in somewhere on the server I ran it on. Running the script on my laptop or other servers (all intel xeon) worked as expected, it's only on the one machine that this weird behavior is found.

I'm just going to be using the other server from now on.

Comment: What dtype is used for the data? As they are all only 1, 0 bool could be used. Also have you considered other ways of holding such apparently sparse data or maybe your sample is not typical.

Comment: dtype was int64, changed it to bool to check but didn't solve the problem. What do you mean by "sample is not typical"?

Comment: Details are missing to help you. Please provide *the code* used to create the dataframe (something [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Indeed, Regarding how this is done, accesses to the dataframe can be significantly slower. The *processor used* and the *amount of available RAM* is critical too. If you do not have enough RAM, then the swap is used and this is typically >10x time slower, especially if you have a slow HDD.

Comment: Unfortunately, proving a minimal example will be difficult because there's a lot happening before these steps, but I understand if this will make it impossible to help me.
In case it's still interesting, the CPU is an Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6128 with 2TB ram, of which only 100GB is used right now so that shouldn't be the problem. But maybe there's something about the cpu..

Comment: Ok so the RAM usage is certainly not the problem. Is this a shared machine? If so another user may slowdown the whole machine. There are other potential source of slowdown like NUMA effects but they are unlikely to cause a >x5 slowdown for this use case. Besides, what OS do you use? I guess it is a Linux, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's a shared linux server I'm SSHed into. Other people are using it, which shouldn't be the source of the prople though as this is a consistent problem, even if I'm the only one running something at that time.

Comment: Do you get the same issue with Numpy arrays? If yes, Is the time growing linearly with the input size (both row and columns) for a Numpy arrays? How long does it takes to do `arr = np.full((256*1024, 1024), 42, dtype=np.int32)` and to do `arr.copy()`. It should take less than 1 second.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why this operation takes so long. Are you sure you have only numeric data in your dataframe ?
My computer (a decent I7 8th generation) takes only 30 seconds to perform this task for a dataframe with **1000** columns and 900k rows.

```
import time

df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,1,(900_000,1000)))

start_time = time.time()
df_test.cumsum()
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
```

In case this is not an issue of type. You can speed things up by converting your dataframe to numpy array before doing this task :

```
df_test.to_numpy().cumsum(axis=0)
```

This leads to a ~30% time reduction for this task.

Comment: Interesting, I am running this task since 6 minues now and it's not finished. It's running on a 50 core server at work I'm SSHed into, maybe there's something about that that's causing the problem? I will try getting some of the data onto my local machine and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: You're not taking advantage of your 50 cores with pandas. Have you tried to use dask to parallelize this task ? But sure, the connection surely impact the performance.

Comment: I was going to use multiprocessing and divide the workload (theres ~60k dfs) but I haven't heard of dask before, I will look into that!